# how to write an object as key if property is undefined

Tags: javascript, object, testing

When writing tests, I `JSON.stringify` all the inputs and assign them to an object as keys, then assign that key the actual value like so:

`tests[JSON.stringify(test)] = test`

The problem is that `JSON.stringify({color: undefined})` = `{}` just the same as if `JSON.stringify({})` = `{}`

Anyone have an idea for a modified or different approach?

Comment: `JSON.stringify({'color': 'undefined'})`?

Comment: `{color: null}`, `{color: false}` or `{color: ''}` might also work. Depends on the purpose of the JSON.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change the properties or initialize them with something other than `undefined` then use a [**replacer**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) an pass it to `stringify` like this:

```js
var obj = {key: "value", color: undefined, other: null};

// this function will be run over all key-value pairs in the object
function replacer(key, value) {
  if(value === undefined) // if the value is undefined
    return 'undefined';   // then return a string 'undefined' (or null if you want)
  return value;
}

// then pass replacer as second parameter to stringify
var str = JSON.stringify(obj, replacer);

console.log(str);
```